# Recharts.js ResponsiveContainer showing padding-like whitespace

Tags: javascript, css, recharts

While using `<ResponsiveContainer>` in [Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer), it renders padding-like whitespace which appear around the chart inside it.

This issue is reproducible here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ykq2q0z871

[Please note the space between the red border of the `<ResponsiveContainer>` and the blue `<LineChart>`.]

How do I remove that so that the line chart renders from edge-to-edge in the red box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All Chart types on `recharts` have a `margin` prop, which [defaults](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart#margin) to:

`{ top: 5, left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 }`

Just adding the modified prop to `<LineChart />`  should fix the issue:

```
<LineChart margin={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }} data={data}>
```

Here is the forked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9m3xj4o76).